# expo / turtle cli isn't update android versionCode when build (standalone app)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm building a standalone app using turtle cli, and i have a trouble with android versionCode in my app.json, turtle cli doesn't update it and cannot deploy to google play store

- I tried putting the versionCode as number and not working.
- I tried putting the versionCode as String and not working.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Trekko",
    "slug": "TrekkoReactNative",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.5",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.belizarsoft.trekko",
      "versionCode": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to publish your app on expo server before building it, by clicking on “publish” on expo XDE or exp publish on the terminal.

And versionCode must be an integer.

Comment: but i'm don't using expo, i'm using turtle cli
I followed this documentation
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/distribution/turtle-cli/